# Print between special characters with sed,grep

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I need to print the string between these characters....

```
atob('       ')
```

I am using a `=` in the second part as an attempt to stop the code on an equal signs (which the base64 string I'm trying to get ends in.)

I use this script, but it prints the entire line containing the above characters.  I need just the data in between.

```
  sed -n '/atob/,${p;/==/q;}'
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work (tested for GNU sed 4.2.2)?

```
 sed -n -e "s/atop('\(.*\)')/\1/p" b.txt
```

where b.txt is

```
atop('safdasdfasf')
```

or you can try awk

```
awk -F\' '/atop/ {print $2}' b.txt
```

(tested for gnu awk 4.0.2 and added the suggestion by Jotne)

Comment: It still seems to print the entire line. (Before and after the start and stop)

Comment: awk works perfect!  You are a legend.  I appreciate this very much.

Comment: `awk` should be `awk -F\' '/atop/ {print $2}'` to make it clear that its only `atop` filed that should be extracted, same as in `sed`

Answer (score 0):

And another working sed:

```
echo "atop('safdasdfasf')" | sed -r "/atop/ s/^[^']+'([^']+)'.*/\1/"
safdasdfasf
```